# HorizontalScrollView does not work in SlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, android-scrollview, slideup, android-event, android-sliding

The layout is like the following.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </ScrollView>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

The version of SlidingUpPanelLayout library is 3.3.1.
ScrollView can slide normally, but the HorizontalScrollView has a sliding conflict

Answer (score 0):

Delete parent `ScrollView` and use only `HorizontalScrollView`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.SlidingTabStrip
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.SlidingTabStrip>
```

And put any parent view inside `HorizontalScrollView`.